# SortedDictionary not Sorting?

Tags: c#, sorteddictionary

So, I have a sorted dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<int, Gene> genes;
```

And I add pairs with the following function:

```
public void createGene(int geneId)
    {
        genes.Add(geneId, new Gene(geneId));
    }
```

In a function which concatenates two Genes thereby deleting one Gene and inserting the new sequence into one of the two Genes. I remove a Gene from the Dictionary like so, proceeding to update the other gene with its new sequence:

```
species[specieId].getGenes().Remove(geneTwoId);
species[specieId].getGene(geneOneId).setSequence(newSequence);
```

Proceeding which I add another pair (Id and Gene) using the following function:

```
public void duplicate(int specieId, int newGeneId, int oldGeneId)
    {
        species[specieId].createGene(newGeneId);

        string duplicateSeq = species[specieId].getGene(oldGeneId).getSequence();

        species[specieId].getGene(newGeneId).createSequence(duplicateSeq);
    }
```

But later when I iterate over the list

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        string specieString = "";

        foreach(var entry in genes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current gene: {0}", entry.Key);
            specieString += ">SE" + id + "_" + entry.Value.ToString();
        }

        return specieString;
    }
```

The returned string will not be ordered by the keys, e.g. I have genes 1, 2, 3. Perform fusion on 2 and 3, thereby removing 2, and then 'duplicate' 3 into a gene with Id and Key 4.

The returned string from ToString() will have the order Gene1 Gene4 Gene3

I believe I must be using the Remove and Add functions incorrectly as I had this issue occur with a F# implementation of this program which also uses dictionary's.

Comment: Your example prints objects 1, 3, 4 for me in that order when I run it in the C# Interactive REPL, .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q7EvjT).

Comment: You might as well show us your actual code, what you're showing us would never actually happen. The enumerators go through the entries ordered by the key. Since you don't provide an alternate comparer, the keys will just be in the natural numeric order.

Comment: `private Dictionary<int, Gene> genes;` <-- doesn't look sorted to me..

Comment: I am an idiot, too long staring at the same code.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your sorted dictionary?

```
private Dictionary<int, Gene> genes;
```

This does not create a sorted dictionary. In order to create a sorted dictionary you should use:

```
private SortedDictionary<int, Gene> genes;
```

And then initialize it where needed using

```
genes = new SortedDictionary<int, Gene>();
```